# Error transforming dates to days in r

Tags: r

I am adding a day-name column to a data frame that has a date column. Something like this:

```
date<-c ("01/09/2014", "24/08/2014", "28/08/2014")
id<-(1:3)
df<-data.frame(date,id)
df$day<-weekdays(as.Date(df$date))
```

However, the resulting column does not match the actual days. In the above example, for instance, September 1 is Thursday, while in reality it was a Monday. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To see why it was incorrect, just run: `as.Date(df$date)
`

Comment: @BondedDust: yes, but the behaviour seems to deviate from (my interpretation of) `?as.Date`, which says of `"format"`" `If not specified, it will try ‘"%Y-%m-%d"’ then ‘"%Y/%m/%d"’ on the first non-‘NA’ element` ??

Comment: I thought it should have thrown an error as well, However, it did "try" "%Y-%m-%d"and manage to pull 01 , 09, and  20 from "01/09/2014" and made "0001-09-20"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the formatting when you call `as.Date()`.  Try this code:

```
df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Be careful with the last formatting parameter.  If you use lowercase y, `%y`, you will get the wrong answer.

```
> df
        date id      day
1 01/09/2014  1   Monday
2 24/08/2014  2   Sunday
3 28/08/2014  3 Thursday
```